# data retrieval from database into a variable with C#

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

hi i am trying to store data from the database into a variable and then trying to process it.
but somehow the variable does not read any data from the database and gives its initial value.
heres the code

```
int c1=0,c2=0.c3=0,c4=0,sum;

if (rbFour.Checked == true)
        {
            proce = cmb1.Text + "," + cmb2.Text + "," + cmb3.Text + "," + cmb4.Text;
            SqlDataAdapter d = new SqlDataAdapter("Select Amount from addpro where SSN=" + cmb1.ValueMember, Program.con);
            DataTable t = new DataTable();
            foreach (DataRow row in t.Rows)
            {

            c1 = Convert.ToInt32(row[0]);
        }
        SqlDataAdapter qd = new SqlDataAdapter("Select Amount from addpro where SSN=" + cmb2.ValueMember, Program.con);
        DataTable qt = new DataTable();
        foreach (DataRow row in qt.Rows)
        {

            c2 = Convert.ToInt32(row[0]);
        }
        SqlDataAdapter wd = new SqlDataAdapter("Select Amount from addpro where SSN=" + cmb3.ValueMember, Program.con);
        DataTable wt = new DataTable();
        foreach (DataRow row in wt.Rows)
        {

            c3 = Convert.ToInt32(row[0]);
        }
        SqlDataAdapter ed = new SqlDataAdapter("Select Amount from addpro where SSN=" + cmb4.ValueMember, Program.con);
        DataTable et = new DataTable();
        foreach (DataRow row in et.Rows)
        {

            c4 = Convert.ToInt32(row[0]);
        }
    }
    else if (rbThree.Checked == true)
    {
        proce = cmb1.Text + "," + cmb2.Text + "," + cmb3.Text;
        SqlDataAdapter d = new SqlDataAdapter("Select Amount from addpro where SSN=" + cmb1.ValueMember, Program.con);
        DataTable t = new DataTable();
        foreach (DataRow row in t.Rows)
        {

            c1 = Convert.ToInt32(row[0]);
        }
        SqlDataAdapter qd = new SqlDataAdapter("Select Amount from addpro where SSN=" + cmb2.ValueMember, Program.con);
        DataTable qt = new DataTable();
        foreach (DataRow row in qt.Rows)
        {

            c2 = Convert.ToInt32(row[0]);
        }
        SqlDataAdapter wd = new SqlDataAdapter("Select Amount from addpro where SSN=" + cmb3.ValueMember, Program.con);
        DataTable wt = new DataTable();
        foreach (DataRow row in wt.Rows)
        {

            c3 = Convert.ToInt32(row[0]);
        }
    }
    else if (rbTwo.Checked == true)
    {
        proce = cmb1.Text + "," + cmb2.Text;
        SqlDataAdapter d = new SqlDataAdapter("Select Amount from addpro where SSN=" + cmb1.ValueMember, Program.con);
        DataTable t = new DataTable();

        foreach (DataRow row in t.Rows)
        {

            c1 = Convert.ToInt32(row[0]);
        }
        SqlDataAdapter qd = new SqlDataAdapter("Select Amount from addpro where SSN=" + cmb2.ValueMember, Program.con);
        DataTable qt = new DataTable();
        qd.Fill(qt);
        foreach (DataRow row in qt.Rows)
        {

            c2 = Convert.ToInt32(row[0]);
        }

    }
    else
    {
        proce = cmb1.Text;
        SqlDataAdapter d = new SqlDataAdapter("Select Amount from addpro where SSN=" + cmb1.ValueMember, Program.con);
        DataTable t = new DataTable();
        foreach (DataRow row in t.Rows)
        {

            c1 = Convert.ToInt32(row[0]);
        }
    }
```

can anyone help with this.i used the same code few days ago.it worked fine.but now i dont know whats wrong with it.
i need the solution asap can anyone help plz?

Comment: use , not . after c2=0,c3=0 "int c1=0,c2=0,c3=0,c4=0,sum;",what's the error you are getting...

Comment: You are missing the code that fills your `DataTable`. See [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=dataadapter+datatable) for examples.

Comment: thanx for your comments its was with Fill() field. the table wasnt filled with fields.
issue solved thanx @mbeckish

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to [Fill](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/905keexk.aspx) a DataTable before using it

```
  SqlDataAdapter d = new SqlDataAdapter("...", con);
  DataTable t = new DataTable();
  d.Fill(t);  // Here
```

and so on for the remaining adapters.

However, let me show a different approach:

```
string sqlText = "Select Amount from addpro where SSN=@ssn";
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlText, Program.con);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ssn", cmb1.ValueMember);
object result = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
if(result != null)
    c1 = Convert.ToInt32(result);
```

You are returning a single row with a single value (if found). This is the usage scenario provided by the [ExecuteScalar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar.aspx) method of the SqlCommand. There is no need to create a SqlAdapter, a DataTable and fill it with a single row/value.

Also, I have removed your string concatenation and used Parametrized queries to avoid Sql Injection Attacks. Albeit, in your code is a bit improbable, it is a good practice to use everywhere.

With the above code in place it is really easy to build a common method that receives the combobox control, apply the logic required and return the integer value

```
 private int GetComboValue(ComboBox cbo)
 {
      // all the code above replacing cmb1 with cbo and c1 with ssnNumber
      .....
      return ssnNumber;
 }
```

and now you can use

```
if (rbFour.Checked == true)
{
   c1 = GetComboValue(cmb1);
   c2 = GetComboValue(cmb2);
   c3 = GetComboValue(cmb3);
   c4 = GetComboValue(cmb4);
}
```

Comment: issue solved.
thanx for the additional code. i will use it in my application
thanx a tonne

Answer (score 0):

Use the fill() method to fill the datatable first with the dataadapter and then try to access the data rows

ex: d.fill(dt);